# Android - Error in Google Drive API implementation

Tags: android, api, google-drive-api

I've been following the [Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android), doing all available steps, then try running it on my phone...
The application works perfectly, but it shows blank activity right after I take a picture from camera (for upload)...

I watched the video (inside the link above), and noticed that the blank activity is also shown on the working application, right after taking a picture... Then after a moment, it displays a permission window... But on my phone, the blank activity stays no matter how long I wait for it (no permission window shown)... Then I tried checking my google drive, but found no uploaded file...

I tried to use logcat, and here is the result:

```
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996): {
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):   "code": 403,
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):   "errors": [
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):     {
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):       "domain": "usageLimits",
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):       "message": "Access Not Configured",
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):     }
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):   ],
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):   "message": "Access Not Configured"
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996): }
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:426)
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):    at id.ac.petra.ta.Backup$1.run(Backup.java:96)
05-07 10:47:08.596: W/System.err(15996):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Do anyone have an idea why the app is not working?
I've spent almost a week just to figure out what is going on, but still no luck... Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have registered your signature's footprint on the APIs console. We had a similar issue with our Android application.